# HtmlUnit NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, htmlunit

I've been working with HtmlUnit (version 2.9) to build an android app that gets data from a website. The code compiles fine, but when I click the "Login" button, it crashes because a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when it reaches the WebUnit variable initialization. I've added the jars to `Project/lib`.

**Relevant code:**

```
public void doLogin(View v) {
    if (uname.getText().toString() == "" || pass.getText().toString() == "") {

        makeToast("Missing at least one of the following: Username, Password");
        Log.e("RobloxApp", "Missing a username and/or password");
        return;         
    } else {                
            try {                   
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                HtmlPage page = client.getPage(RbxRes.Urls.loginPage);

                HtmlInput unameInput = (HtmlInput)  page.getElementById(RbxRes.Elements.uNameId); 
                HtmlInput passInput  = (HtmlInput)  page.getElementById(RbxRes.Elements.passId);
                HtmlButton loginBtn  = (HtmlButton) page.getElementById(RbxRes.Elements.loginId);

                unameInput.setTextContent(uname.getText().toString());
                passInput.setTextContent(pass.getText().toString());
                loginBtn.click();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("RobloxApp", "The following error occurred while trying to login: " + e.getMessage());
                makeToast("Error: Could not login");
                return;
            }
    }
```

**Logcat output:**

```
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at andr oid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     ... 11 more
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     at com rbx.robloxapp.Login.doLogin(Login.java:46)
 07-14 04:38:46.357: E/AndroidRuntime(708):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: It seems to  HtmlUnit's jar is missing from your classpath.

Comment: @Ajmal I thought I'd already done that: http://imgur.com/hy1Pq. I can't post the picture in the thread because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: It seems like you add as a external jar. It should add like, First create a lib folder in your project and copy jar files into it. Then go to properties use add jar option and select lib/some.jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your jar in `libs` instead then right click on it and choose `Add to Build Path`

Comment: When I did that, it wouldn't even build. The error message I got suggests that the jar was incorrectly built, and says I should re-compile them from source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your library in AndroidManifest.xml, like `google map library <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>`?

Comment: When I add that to the manifest, it won't build. 07-14 06:03:01.115: E/PackageManager(93): Package com.rbx.robloxapp requires unavailable shared library com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient; failing!